# What's the meaning of "mimic" in this case?

Tags: meaning

https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=xBNGDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&lpg=PT56&dq=%22mimic+the+right+brain+patterns%22&source=bl&ots=hxI38QLf7m&sig=SrxXaDaiFfXOTRNnycyy1UoZ-hs&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiursnAlKvUAhWMDsAKHZdbC3UQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22mimic%20the%20right%20brain%20patterns%22&f=false

The main text: 
For decades, researchers believed this activity was the root of addiction: **mimic** the right brain patterns and you'd create an addict.

Answer (score 1):

"Mimic" in this example means **to imitate** or **to copy**.

I hope this answers your question.